# How to debug Ansible dict for failed ports with wait_for module?

Tags: linux, ansible, port, ansible-playbook, debug

I have written the below playbook to fetch the failed port status.

```yaml
  - name: Check  port status
    wait_for:
     host: 127.0.0.1
     port: "{{ item }}"
     timeout: 2
     state: started
    ignore_errors: yes
    with_items:
     - 80
     - 22
     - 8080
    register: wait_result

  - debug:
     msg: "{{ 'Failed with message: ' ~ wait_result.msg  if wait_result.failed else 'Success' }}"
```

While fetching the `msg` from debug logs I am unable to get the timeout message.

```json
PLAY [mysrv] ************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Check Nagios port status] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=80)
ok: [localhost] => (item=22)
failed: [localhost] (item=8080) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "elapsed": 2, "item": 8080, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for 127.0.0.1:8080"}
...ignoring

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Failed with message: One or more items failed"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
```

Can someone please help to correct my code?

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can write the messages

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in wait_result.results|select('failed') %}
          {{ i.msg }}
          {% endfor %}
```

, or create a list and use it later

```yaml
  failed_msg: "{{ wait_result.results|
                  select('failed')|
                  map(attribute='msg')|list }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    failed_msg: "{{ wait_result.results|
                    select('failed')|
                    map(attribute='msg')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Check  port status
      wait_for:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: "{{ item }}"
        timeout: 2
        state: started
      register: wait_result
      ignore_errors: yes
      loop: [22, 25, 53, 80]

    - debug:
        var: wait_result
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - debug:
        var: failed_msg

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in wait_result.results|select('failed') %}
          {{ i.msg }}
          {% endfor %}

    - assert:
        that: wait_result.results|select('failed')|length == 0
        fail_msg: |
          {% for i in wait_result.results|select('failed') %}
          {{ i.msg }}
          {% endfor %}
        success_msg: All services started.
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Check  port status] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=22)
ok: [localhost] => (item=25)
failed: [localhost] (item=53) => changed=false 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  elapsed: 2
  item: 53
  msg: Timeout when waiting for 127.0.0.1:53
failed: [localhost] (item=80) => changed=false 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  elapsed: 2
  item: 80
  msg: Timeout when waiting for 127.0.0.1:80
...ignoring

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  failed_msg:
  - Timeout when waiting for 127.0.0.1:53
  - Timeout when waiting for 127.0.0.1:80

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    Timeout when waiting for 127.0.0.1:53
    Timeout when waiting for 127.0.0.1:80

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: wait_result.results|select('failed')|length == 0
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: |-
    Timeout when waiting for 127.0.0.1:53
    Timeout when waiting for 127.0.0.1:80

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=1
```

Comment: I tried both method suggested in your code and now I am able to get the failed msg printed in debug msg. Thank you.